# Laravel: Missing argument 1 for AdminController::getUpdateUser()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to larevel and i've been trying to solve this problem starting yesterday up to now and haven't make any progress and im stuck here....

PLEASE HELP :(

Here's my code for the **routes:**

```
Route::get('/admin/edit', array('uses' => 'AdminController@getUpdateUser', 'as' => 'getUpdateUser'));

Route::resource('admin1', 'AdminController');
```

---

Here's my code for the button viewing the update **(I think the problem might be here and i cant think of a code that will call the id D: )**

```
    {{ link_to_action('AdminController@getUpdateUser', 'Edit', array($users->id),array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
```

--
Here's my code at my **AdminController**:

```
public function getUpdateUser($id)
{


     $users = User::find($id);


    //load view and pass users  
    return View::make('admin.edit')
        ->with('users', $users);


}



public function updateUser($id)
{

    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'middlename' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'birthday' => 'required',
        'contact' => 'required|numeric',
        'email' => 'required'
    ));


      if ($validate->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('admin.edit')
            ->withErrors($validate)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));

         }
         else
            {

       $user = User::find($id);
      $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->middlename = Input::get('middlename');
        $user->address = Input::get('address');
        $user->birthday = Input::get('birthday');
        $user->contact = Input::get('contact');
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        if($user->save())

            {
            return Redirect::route('admin.view')->with('success', 'USER HAS BEEN UPDATED');
        }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('admin.view')->with('fail', 'An error occured while updating the user. Please double check your inputs and try again.');
            }
        }
}
```

---

Here's my code for **admin.edit**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('head')
@parent
<title>Manage Users</title>
@stop



@section('content')

<div class ="container">
<h1>Edit User</h1>

{{ Form::model($users, array('route' => array('admin1.updateUser', $users-     >id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}


--textboxes and inputs here--


{{ Form::submit('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
```

Please help me T_T THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you missed is putting the id actually in the route URL as a [route parameter](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters). Like this:

```
Route::get('/admin/edit/{id}', array('uses' => 'AdminController@getUpdateUser', 'as' => 'getUpdateUser'));
```